# UIWebView not getting next Url to Load

Tags: ios

I am working on a native cum web iOS app. When i try to load Urls in UIWebView on any button press inside WebView i am unable to get the next URL to be loaded. Can anyone suggest anything for this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my Code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *myString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    [myString lowercaseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",myString)
    NSDictionary *headers = [request allHTTPHeaderFields];
    BOOL hasReferer = [headers objectForKey:@"X"]!=nil;
    if (hasReferer)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        // relaunch with a modified request
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSURL *url = [request URL];
                NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
                [request setValue:X forHTTPHeaderField:@"X"];
                [request setValue:Y forHTTPHeaderField:@"Y"];                   
                [loadingWebView loadRequest:request];
            });
        });

        return NO;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for better understanding

Comment: i am unable to get the next URL to be loaded ..? - is not clear

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik:  I have a WebPage And on that WebPage their is a button on Clicking it I should be redirected to the next page but it is not doing that since i am not getting the URL of next page to be loaded. Whereas in anroid app it is getting redirected to next page.

Answer (score 0):

set delegate

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(nullable NSError *)error;
```

see in this method what it returns

and make sure you are passing correct url ie `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer i have already implemented these methods , I am getting my first URL again in shouldStartLoadWithRequest..